# Find minimal polynomial of element

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Find minimal polynomial of element $3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$ $\in {\displaystyle \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) } $ over the field $ {\displaystyle \mathbb {Q} } $.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the mistake, I am not sure how to start,one simple example minimal polynomial of element $\sqrt{2}$ over the field $  {\displaystyle \mathbb {Q} } .$ is $x^2-2$. But I don't know how to work with ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) }$

Comment: Take something more interesting from that ring, then. Like $1-2\sqrt 2$. What's the minimal polynomial of _that_ element? How did you find that polynomial?

Comment: I do not know if I am correct but coefficients have to be from ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Q} } $, it means that polynomial of degree 1 is not good. I have tried $x^2+ax+b$ and finally I have got polynomial $x^2-2x-7$. But I'm still confused how the fact ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) }$ is important. Thanks!

Comment: Try to be more systematic about it. If we set $x = 1-2\sqrt 2$, then we have $1-x = 2\sqrt2$, so $(1-x)^2 = 8$, which makes $(1-x)^2 - 8 = x^2 - 2x - 7$ into the minimal polynomial (well, _a_ polynomial, but as you said linear polynomials aren't going to be enough, so it's actually mimnimal). Now do the same to your number.

Comment: Thank you ver much, now it is more clear for me. But what is stil strange for me is why is important that $3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$ $\in {\displaystyle \mathbb {Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}) } $, the result is same when we say $3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$ $\in {\displaystyle \mathbb {R} } $

Comment: It's not important at all. The important part is that we are looking for a minimal polynomial _over $\Bbb Q$_. But think of it this way: It allowed me to catch your typo. It means we can _know_ that a third degree polynomial will suffice (although excluding the possibility of a second degree polynomial takes some theory). In summary, it's there for convenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a systematic way to find the minimal polynomial, which works in general setting. We know that $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now consider the following relations:

$$(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})\cdot1 = 3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}$$
$$(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})\cdot \sqrt[3]{2} = -2 + 3\sqrt[3]{2} - 2\sqrt[3]{4}$$
$$(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})\cdot \sqrt[3]{4} = -4 - 2\sqrt[3]{2} + 3 \sqrt[3]{4}$$

These three equations can be written in matrix notation in the following way:

$$ (3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  \sqrt[3]{2}\\
  \sqrt[3]{4}
\end{array}
\right]  =  \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  3&-2&-1\\
  -2&3&-2\\
  -4&-2&3
\end{array}
\right]\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1\\
  \sqrt[3]{2}\\
  \sqrt[3]{4}
\end{array}
\right] $$

This gives us that $(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix on the right. Hence it's a zero of the polynomial $\det(xI-M)$. Obviously as the degree of it is $3$ and $(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4}) \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ we get that it must be the minimal polynomial of $(3-2\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4})$. Evaluating the determinant isn't a hard thing to do and you will get that the minimal polynomial is:

$$f(x) = x^3 - 9x^2 + 15x + 29$$